# Cannot pull WYSIWYG content

Tags: pages, content

I am having trouble trying to pull then content from the page's WYSIWYG editor.

The template index.php file is set up like nothing I have seen before and I am simply trying to sort this out. I have tried using the loop method (which should always be used) i have tried another method by defining the content function in the index.php and nothing seems to work. The closest I get is pulling the most recent post on to the page rather than the WYSIWYG content.

This is the other attempt with the Loop put in. This relays no content from the WYSIWYG editor on to the page:

```
   <?php 
get_header(); 

$homeId = 187;
$roomImg = get_field("front_room_image", $homeId); 
$middleImg = get_field("middle_image", $homeId);
$cornerImg = get_field("right_bottom_corner", $homeId);
$ipadcornerImg = get_field("right_bottom_corner_ipad", $homeId);
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($middleImg['id'], 'front-middle-image');
$roomSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($roomImg['id'], 'floor-image');
$cornerImgSrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($cornerImg['id'], 'right-bottom-corner');
$cornerImgSrcIpad = wp_get_attachment_image_src($ipadcornerImg['id'], 'right-bottom-corner-ipad');
$rightCornerImg = ((wp_is_mobile()) ? $cornerImgSrcIpad[0] : $cornerImgSrc[0]);
$email = get_post_meta($homeId, "insert_email", true);
$skype = get_post_meta($homeId, "skype_user_name", true);
$slider = array('post_type' => 'wpt_slider', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'posts_status' => 'publish');
$posts = get_posts($slider);
$req = new wp_query($slider);
$menuLabel = get_field("menu_blog", $homeId);
$middle_image_laptop = get_field("middle_image_laptop", $homeId);
$midId = $middle_image_laptop['id'];
$front_room_image_laptop = get_field("front_room_image_laptop", $homeId);
$friID = $front_room_image_laptop['id'];

$mid_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($midId, 'middle_image_laptop');
$fri_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($friID, 'front_room_image_laptop');
    $content = get_the_content( $more_link_text, $strip_teaser );

    /**
     * Filters the post content.
     *
     * @since 0.71
     *
     * @param string $content Content of the current post.
     */
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace( ']]>', ']]&gt;', $content );

?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
      /*//Super Slides
      $('.slides').superslides({
        inherit_width_from: '.wide-container',
        inherit_height_from: '.wide-container',
         animation: 'slide',
        play:6000
      });*/

      //Super Slides
          $('.slides').superslides({
            inherit_width_from: '.wide-container',
            inherit_height_from: '.wide-container',
             animation: 'slide',
            play:6000
          });
        //Super Slides
          $('.slides1').superslides({
            inherit_width_from: '.wide-container1',
            inherit_height_from: '.wide-container1',
             animation: 'slide',
            play:false
          });
        //Super Slides
          $('.slides2').superslides({
            inherit_width_from: '.wide-container2',
            inherit_height_from: '.wide-container2',
             animation: 'slide',
            play:false
          });
        //Super Slides
          $('.slides3').superslides({
            inherit_width_from: '.wide-container3',
            inherit_height_from: '.wide-container3',
             animation: 'slide',
            play:false
          });
        //Super Slides
          $('.slides4').superslides({
            inherit_width_from: '.wide-container4',
            inherit_height_from: '.wide-container4',
             animation: 'slide',
            play:false
          });

    });
</script>



<div id="content-area">
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
  <div><p><?php the_content(); ?></p></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
  <div id="TwelveDrid">
    <section class="BgTransition">
      <div class="wide-container">
        <div class="slides">
          <div class="slides-container"> <?php echo roomSlider(); ?> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the situation. Do you use `the_content()` and you don't get the expected result? What result do you expect and what you get instead? Note that index.php is a very generic template file, although pages can use this template, most themes have dedicated template files for single pages.

Comment: `$posts = get_posts($slider);
$req = new wp_query($slider);` - this could very well interfere with the main loop - thus your main loop actually doesn't do anything.
Try not using get_posts, but use only WP_Query, and after you used it, use `wp_reset_query();` to return to the main loop.

Comment: @cybmeta Yes I am using the_content() to try and pull the content from wordpress standard WYSIWYG editor. This is not working for the root page "/" but it relays the content out to the /home/ page. The only problem is that all the previous changes made to index.php relay to the root and not '/home/'. Even when I just hard code the information straight into index.php it shows on the root but not /home/.

Comment: What is your configuration in "Settings->Reading->Your homepage displays"? I think that you incorrectly expect `index.php` template be used when it is not.